# JNA map Java String to PCWSTR

Tags: java, c, shell, jna

```
SHSTDAPI SHCreateItemFromParsingName(
  PCWSTR   pszPath,
  IBindCtx *pbc,
  REFIID   riid,
  void     **ppv
);
```

I tried to map the above method to this method:

```
WinNT.HRESULT SHCreateItemFromParsingName(String pszPath, Pointer p, Guid.REFIID riid, PointerByReference ppv);
```

EDIT:

```
PointerByReference ppv = new PointerByReference();

        Guid.REFIID rid = new Guid.REFIID(new Guid.IID(Shell32Extra.IID_IShellItem));

        WinNT.HRESULT h = Shell32Extra.INSTANCE.SHCreateItemFromParsingName("*.txt",null,rid,ppv);

        IShellItem shellItem = new IShellItem(ppv.getValue());
```

But the HRESULT throws failed with -2147024894

And if pbc is not null, it will throw an Memory access expection

What should I change? I think it maybe is failing because of the PCWSTR mapping.

Comment: (Windows) `PCWSTR` is (C) `const wchar_t *` (null-terminated) and the javadoc says that (like the non-const form) should be `WString`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While technomage points out mapping errors, these wouldn't be giving you the result you got.  The `HRESULT` of -2147024894 indicates the system can't find the file.  Your `dd.txt` file is not in the path that the program has access to.

Additionally you can use the `WString` type to specify that you need a wide string.  Wrap your `dd.txt` (or longer path) in a `WString` constructor and pass that.

Comment: I change the path several times to real files but nothing has changed.

Comment: You might need a WString:  `WString dd = new WString("dd.txt");`

Comment: A new HRESULT is thrown now which says CO_E_NOTINITIALIZED (-2147221008)

Comment: Well, intialize COM then! :)  `hres = Ole32.INSTANCE.CoInitializeEx(null, Ole32.COINIT_MULTITHREADED);` and `hres = Ole32.INSTANCE.CoInitializeSecurity(null, -1, null, null, Ole32.RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_DEFAULT, Ole32.RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, null, Ole32.EOAC_NONE, null);` (don't forget to uninitialize when you're done.)

Comment: I have one last question.                                                                                       I have this method:                                                                               
HRESULT GetImage(
  SIZE    size,
  SIIGBF  flags,
  HBITMAP *phbm
);                                                                                                                                   SIIGBF is an enum with int. Which type should I pass in in Java (int or IntByReference...)?

Comment: Since the signature is `SIIGBF flags` you directly map an `int`.  If it was `*flags` you would use the IntByReference.  The exception to this rule in JNA is structures, which are "automatically" pointers.

Comment: I have tried that already. But it throws an access expecton. The method is this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ishellitemimagefactory-getimage

Comment: Are you using one of the allowed integer values at that link?

Comment: I think yes (0x00000000)

Comment: Not sure I'm of much more help.  Might try a new question specific to the problem you're having.

Comment: I created a new question. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52348991/jna-invalid-memory-access-ishellitemimagefactory)

Answer (score 0):

Your second argument should be a pointer to struct, not the address of an integer value (`IntByReference`).  If you're not going to use it, leave it as a `Pointer`. 
In this case, passing `null` should be fine.

You do not need to initialize the `PointerByReference`.  JNA will pass a memory buffer that will be initialized by the called function; you can then call `.getValue()` to retrieve the returned pointer value, which will be the `IShellItem[2]`.

Comment: Thanks.  I changed the method as you can see above. But the returned value is still null and the HRESULT is -2147024894 too